# rails generate random number on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a guessing number game in Ruby on Rails and I am wondering how I could execute a block of code (in this case to generate a random number) when the page completely loads. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rand(9)       # this generator a number between 0 to 8
rand(0 .. 9)  # this generator a number between 0 to 9
rand(1 .. 50) # this generator a number between 1 to 50
#rand(m .. n) # m is the start of generator number range, n is the end of generator number range
```

Comment: Use rand where you want to generate random number.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Array.new(5){rand 10}.join
```

**Advantage:**

The above code will generate the 5 digit random number. You can replace `5` with any number according to how many number of digits you want.

More from [Generating Random Numbers in Ruby](http://ruby.about.com/od/newinruby191/ss/Generating-Random-Numbers-In-Ruby.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use '**SafeRandom**' Gem [GithubLink](https://github.com/rpatil/safe_random)

It will provide the easiest way to generate random values for Rails 2, Rails 3, Rails 4, Rails 5 compatible.

Here you can use the strong_string method to generate a strong combination of string ( ie combination of the alphabet(uppercase, downcase), number, and symbols

Strong string: Minumum number should be greater than 5 otherwise by default 8 character string.

```
require 'safe_random'
puts SafeRandom.strong_string       # => 4skgSy93zaCUZZCoF9WiJF4z3IDCGk%Y
puts SafeRandom.strong_string(3)    # => P4eUbcK%
puts SafeRandom.strong_string(5)    # => 5$Rkdo
```